# KeyError: 0 python with python dict

Tags: python

So I'm trying to re-create a spaceInvaders game with python. Here is where my aliens are stored:

```
aliens = dict()
```

and each time we increase the game level then a new alien is added with it's id as a key and his positions and health(each alien has 2 health and dies after two shots which deal one damage each) as his value, so the aliens dictionary can look like that:

```
aliens = {
0: [(100, 50), 2],
1: [(50, 200), 1],
etc...
}
```

now each time an alien dies I set it's health to `-1` and set his positions to `(-100, -100)` to put him out of the view, now the problem occurs when I call a `cleanAlien()` function which iterates through the alien array and pops every alien that has a health equal to `-1` or an out of bounds position, here is that function:

```
def cleanAliens():
    global aliens
    for i in range(len(aliens)):
        if(aliens[i][0] == (-100, -100) or aliens[i][1] < 0):
            aliens.pop(i);
            i -= i
```

However when I try to run that I get an error:

```sh
if(aliens[i][0] == (-100, -100) or aliens[i][1] < 0):
KeyError: 0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `print(aliens)` in each iteration of the loop and make sure that there is a key=0 in the dict

Comment: @Meccano this is the last output before it raises the error: `{1: [(540, 103), 2], 2: [(218, 110), 2]}`

Comment: Why are doing `i -= i` at end of your loop? Why you choose to write `i = 0` in such untypical manner?

Comment: @Daweo I did that because when I pop an element then the length of the dictionary is reduced, but even without the `i -= 1` it throws me the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Fixed my error by creating a list which is appended each key to be removed which is then passed to this function:

```
def Aliens():
    global aliens
    clean = list()
    for i in aliens.keys():
        if(aliens[i][0] == (-100, -100) or aliens[i][1] < 0):
             clean.append(i)
    cleanAliens(clean)
```

and

```
def cleanAliens(cleanList):
    global aliens
    for i in range(len(cleanList)):
            aliens.pop(cleanList[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for the reason of this specific error, but it seems like the structure of `aliens` is not as expected.

However, you can iterate over the keys of the dictionary instead of over the size of it like so:

```
for i in list(aliens.keys()):
    if aliens[i][0] == (-100, -100) or aliens[i][1] < 0:
        aliens.pop(i)
```

And that way you don't get into this key trouble.

The `list(aliens.keys())` returns a copy of the keys in the dictionary so you iterate over it, and after you remove one from the dictionary, you just continue to the next one.

(btw, the `i -= i` line is meaningless because `i` will be set next iteration according to its iterator, so you can't actually change its value)

Comment: Thank you for your useful response, got me other the error however i now get that: `for i in alien.keys(): 
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: In the same place in the code? I've tested this method on a dummy dictionary and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
for i in range(len(aliens)):
    if(aliens[i][0] == (-100, -100) or aliens[i][1] < 0):
        aliens.pop(i);
        i -= i
```

you should have used a comprehension:

```
aliens = { k:v for k,v in aliens.items() if v[0] != (-100,100) and v[1] >= 0 }
```

---

UPDATE: testing after receiving the comment about "the same error":

```
>>> aliens = {
... 0: [(100, 50), 2],
... 1: [(50, 200), 1],
... }
>>> aliens = { k:v for k,v in aliens.items() if v[0] != (-100,100) and v[1] >= 0 }
>>>
```

There's no error.

Comment: Thanks for your response however that does not work in my case and throws the same error